Why does command-tab in Remote Desktop sometimes target the remote computer's application switcher and sometimes the local computer?
Sometimes when I command-tab in an Apple's Remote Desktop window to switch among applications it opens the remote computer's application switcher and sometimes it activates the local computer's application switcher. I haven't found any pattern in this behaviour or how to influence it, but it is very annoying.
Any ideas how to control/change this?

Are you sure you are in the correct window?

If the remote has focus, it should be passed to the remote.

@SolarMike Yes.

@MarcWilson I agree but something seems to be off with the focus.
